# Passing properties in Semantic MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

Currently I have 3 categories, Application, Application Instance and Vendor.

Right now Application has a link (via property Made By) to Vendor. Application instances need to link back to Vendor via a property. I have the query I can use to return the application name and vendor is

```
{{#ask:
 [[Category:Program]][[{{{Program}}}]]
 |?Made By
}}
```

however

```
{{#set:Made By={{#ask:
 [[Category:Program]][[{{{Program}}}]]
 |?Made By
}}}}
```

doesn't work to set the property to the value of vendor which is returned by the ask query.

Are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late but you could probably do this using a template to set the property. Something like this?

In the Application Instance template (or manually on each Application Instance page) add the following ask query:

```
{{#ask:[[Category:Program]][[{{{Program}}}]]
|?Made By
|link=none
|format=template
|template=Set made by
}}
```

Then create the template "wiki/Template:Set made by" with the following:

```
includeonly>
{{#set:
Made By={{{2}}}
}}
</includeonly>
```

Notes

1. Parameter {{{1}}} is the subject which is the page name and {{{2}}} will be the result for 'Made By'.
2. Stripping the link from the query results prevents the extra text being passed to the set command which would confuse things.
3. You can also use the inverse of properties in queries by adding a minus sign in front of them. (e.g. '-Made By')

Comment: You could also set named args=yes see https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Named_args